# if I change a records values in a listview how do i update the listview so i can see the changes I have made?

Tags: c#, sql

This is my update code but after I do an update to a record in the listview I want the listview to automatically load the changes I have made.

```
private void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dblib.DatabaseConnection.GetConnectionString());

    if (textBoxID.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter values first.");
        return;
    }

    string sql = "update PolicyHolder Set ";
    sql += "Name='" + textBoxName.Text + "' ";
    sql += ",Address='" + textBoxAddress.Text + "' ";
    sql += ",Phone='" + textBoxPhone.Text + "' ";

    sql += " Where ID ='" + textBoxID.Text + "' ";
    textBoxID.Text = string.Empty;
    textBoxName.Text = string.Empty;
    textBoxAddress.Text = string.Empty;
    textBoxPhone.Text = string.Empty;

    MessageBox.Show("Update Success.");

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: While you are at it, I might suggest researching the subject of SQL injection.

Comment: You will need to share the code you have to populate the datasource on the list view for anyone to provide a proper answer.

Comment: If you are not data binding you could simply do the same query you are currently doing to populate the list after you do an update.

Comment: How are you currently binding the list view to the database queries?